# HP Fortify SQL injection issue on preparedStatement in java

Tags: java, jdbc, coding-style, fortify

I am using HP Fortify to measure code quality of my java code.

HP Fortify is reporting **SQL Injection** error on

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connnection.prepareStatement(queryString);
```

so how to resolve this?

Comment: How is `queryString` generated? And are you in general familiar with injection attacks -- that is, are you asking about what a SQL injection is, or why the alert is being triggered on this invocation specifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, HP Fortify will report an error on this scenario if it cannot trace the origin of all the Strings you are using to build your queryString to constants. If any part of the string is read from the disk or passed as a request parameter, then you are at risk of being vulnerable to a SQL injection.

The recommended solution is to never use external strings when building your SQL query string. Your SQL String should only be built from String constants, and every parameter inserted at runtime should be inserted as a bind variable, which means its location should appear as a "?"  in the SQL string, and its value should be set using the setX() methods of the [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) class.

Note that you should always used bind variables when creating PreparedStatements in Java: It's not only a good security practice, it's a good performance practice as it will not require the database to re-parse the SQL query every time a parameter value changes.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't use the user input as a parameter for your prepared statement but instead build your SQL command by joining strings together, you are still vulnerable to SQL injections even when using prepared statements

Comment: Hi Satheesh, could you give an example or point me to a reference that would better explain this claim? From my understanding, as long as the data you use to build your query string is "trusted", the risk is non-existent. Of course, one of the main rules of security is "trust no one", but if someone can get direct access to the server running your code, all bets are off and you might have bigger concerns than potential SQL injections :)